# How to attach timestamp to single track (not points) in GPX file

Tags: carto, gpx, torque

I'm trying to build a Torque visualization with [CartoDB](https://cartodb.com/torque/) based on a GPX file I received from a third-party. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to be formatted quite right as the trkpts don't have timestamps but the trk as a whole does.

Example:

```
<trk>
    <name>02bb8f71fa569898748f1983d78a2c21</name>
    <desc>fd367fa83bb00443b2614da748fa9a40</desc>
    <timestamp>2013-11-25 18:47</timestamp>
    <trkseg>
      <trkpt lat="28.543573333333335" lon="-81.35272833333333"/>
      <trkpt lat="28.543573333333335" lon="-81.35272833333333"/>
      <trkpt lat="28.54366" lon="-81.35315833333334"/>
      <trkpt lat="28.54366" lon="-81.35315833333334"/>
      <trkpt lat="28.54366" lon="-81.35313666666667"/>
    </trkseg>
</trk>
```

It should look like this:

```
<trk>
    <name>02bb8f71fa569898748f1983d78a2c21</name>
    <desc>fd367fa83bb00443b2614da748fa9a40</desc>
    <trkseg>
         <trkpt lat="28.542491666666667" lon="-81.37588166666667">
             <time>2009-10-17T18:37:26Z</time>
         </trkpt>
         <trkpt lat="28.54224333333333" lon="-81.37438">
             <time>2009-10-18T18:37:26Z</time>
         </trkpt>
    </trkseg>
</trk>
```

Is there a way I can still do a Torque visualization without having times for the individual points? After uploading the data into CartoDB, two tables are produced -- one with track information, one with point information. The track table doesn't even include the timestamp associated with it in the GPX, and Torque isn't an option in the Map wizard.

Here is a screen shot of a row from the tracks table:
[image]

And here are two screen shots (table is too wide to fit in one) of the points table.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Could you share with us both tables? Or if you are concerned about privacy, just explained us what contains (columns, data types...) in order to replicate your problem and try to get a solution. :-)

Comment: As I understood you have two datasets generated from a GPS: tracks (lines) and waypoints (points). So you can add these two layers to a CartoDB map and make a Torque map using the `time` column. You can find a video tutorial [here](https://vimeo.com/79115503) and a more elavorated one [here](http://lifewatch.inbo.be/blog/posts/cartodb-tracking-data-tutorial.html).